# How to match a vowel in the beginning of word Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    let regExp = /^[aieou]/;
    let output = str.match(regExp);
    return output;
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));
```

I want to match a vowel in the beginning of the word implementing regex. I search but I don't find a serious result. I want to search on word if begin with consonnant or consonant cluster, and return  `true`. Else, return false.

My code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to `negate` the result to achieve the result

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  let regExp = /^[aieou]/;
  let output = str.match(regExp);
  return !output;
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("alifornia"));
```

You can easily achieve return the boolean value using [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  return !new RegExp("^[aeiou]").test(str);
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("alifornia"));
```